# React Native: Cannot call this.setState with a callback in a node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I have a simple React Native package that works fine when I run the package's example in it's own directory. When I published the module and install it in a separate project, I get the following error:

`this.updater.enqueuecallback is not a function`

When I opened up the module's source code in the node_modules folder and removed a callback from the first call of `this.setState`, the error went away. When I replaced the callback with an empty arrow function, I got the same error. When I copy and paste the same code and import/export it in my src folder, it works fine.

Tha node module I'm referring to is [rn-sprite-sheet](https://github.com/MiLeung/rn-sprite-sheet).

Comment: Can you post a bit of your own code snippet? I suspect it is a binding issue.

Comment: https://github.com/MiLeung/rn-sprite-sheet/blob/master/src/SpriteSheet.js#L74

Breaks here. Remove the callback and no errors occur; although that then makes the code useless.

Comment: Have you tried to use latest stable version of React, i.e. `15.6.1`? Your node module has `^16.0.0-alpha.12` in dependencies, and its local directory may have another version installed

Comment: Tried that, using the exact same versions of react and react native in my tes project and node module, changing dependencies to peerDependencies, but still not working. Current error is "Ambiguous resolution: module '/Users/MyProfile/Desktop/test/index.ios.js' tries to requires 'react-native', but there are several files providing this module. You can delete or fix them:" and then lists the paths to the package.json in my test project and node module.